# IntelliJ and Mecurial: Viewing Locally Committed Changes Before Push

Tags: intellij-idea, version-control

Does anyone know how to view your locally committed changes in IntelliJ for Mecurial before pushing them?  It seems that I can only commit them and then Push through the Mecurial context menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IntelliJ, modified files are blue, deleted (and sometimes untracked) files are red, and new files are green.  After you add them to a commit the color coding should reset itself because it is looking at the latest commit for differences.

Alternatively you can right click on the file, move to git (and presumably mercurial) and click any of the "compare" options

Comment: Thanks for the insight!  Once I add those to a commit, that commit sits in my local repository before I push it.  Is there anyway in IntelliJ to view that local repository for Mecurial before I push it?

Comment: The project view will show all files, but should be up by default.  The Show Changes View under the VCS tab might also be helpful.  I don't think there is a way to see the commit chain from inside IntelliJ through.  You could consider using SourceTree or some other git/mercurial frontend.

Comment: Hmm, bummer.  I was hoping there was an extra window I was missing.  Thanks!